# System.Threading.Thread - perform operation on it

Tags: c#, multithreading, c++-cli

Ok so lets say all I have is the reference of a System.Threading.Thread called thread A and I'm on another thread, lets say thread B. Now I need to execute a bit of code on thread A for a moment, then switch back. Using the reference I have, how can I Invoke thread A to do an action in it?

Well I'm making a c++/cli library. One of my objects has a thread affinity. I enter a method, I need to swap threads like you would in a Dispatcher.Invoke.

```
void AllegroSharp::Display::DrawToBackBuffer(BitmapImage^ image)
{
    al_draw_bitmap(image->GetBitmap(), (float)image->Rect->Position->X, (float)image->Rect->Position->Y, 0);
}
```

DrawToBackBuffer gets called on thread B and al_draw_bitmap needs to be called on Thread A, which I have a reference to. How can I do this on thread A? Thread B is just some thread that c# spawned when I did a Task.Run in managed code.

Comment: Is this Winforms, WPF, or something else?

Comment: Running arbitrary code on a *specific* thread is not generally possible.  Unless the thread co-operates, it must solve the [producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).  Takes a thread-safe queue and loop in the thread that empties it.  Any thread can add items to the queue, a delegate object for example.  The UI thread of a GUI program always solves it, takes Control::Begin/Invoke() or Dispatcher::Begin/Invoke(), probably what you are really asking about.

Comment: Will the Blackboard design pattern do what you want? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_(design_pattern)

Comment: ...or would that be *seriously* over-engineering things?

Answer (score 1):

Threads run one set of instructions from start to finish.  If thread A is already running, it will execute whatever code it's been told to run from start to finish.  You won't be able to change what it's running unless it is actively monitoring some shared memory for instructions on what to do next.  Typically the way you implement this is by having a thread run in a loop and, inside that loop, check a message queue.  Then have other threads add messages to that queue to give the looping thread work to do.  There are a lot more details to make it work right, but that's the basic idea.

If, in your particular scenario, thread A is the application's GUI thread, this message passing mechanism is already set up for you, and you can use `Control.Invoke` (winforms) or `Dispatcher.Invoke` (WPF) to pass a unit of work to the GUI thread and wait for it to be completed.

Edit: this answer has been rendered less applicable by the addition of new information to the question.  Ah well.